# Moving a zookeeper server to new physical box

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have a zookeeper ensemble with 3 server with ensemble cfg as

ensemble configuration

    `server.1=zoo01:2888:3888
    server.2=zoo02:2888:3888
    server.3=zoo03:2888:3888`

Note zoo01 is a entry in etc/hosts file.

I have to move zoo01 to a different physical box, but I want to retain it's identity (myid)

Is this possible ? If so, how can I achieve this. I can take a very short down time if required

Comment: i don't understand your question.can you be more specific ? Are you bringing down zoo01 box and adding a new physical box with same zoo01 hostname ?

Comment: yes, 
I want to move zoo01 server to new physical box with same zoo01 hostname

Comment: first bring down the old zoo01 server, then copy the configuration file zk.cfg ,zk.dyn.cfg  and myid file  to new physical box. When you start zk server on new physical box,it should sync the data with other zk servers. Also make sure that the other zk servers are up and running and has quorum in the cluster before starting the new zk server.